Nvidia driver install error
I have a Vaio vpccw21fx with Nvidia GeForce 310m, 8GB of DDR3 RAM and a Seagate Barracuda Q1 SSD, After fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04 on this device, when I try to install my Nvidia drivers I am met with this unprecedented error.


Old Nvidia drivers have problems with the 6.5 kernel (and the gcc-12 compiler), so try the 5.15 kernel. Add the graphics-drivers PPA to see if they have old drivers, Ubuntu's standard repos for Nvidia drivers only go back to 470.  Have you tried 470?

The nearest package to your requirements in Ubuntu 22.04 is nvidia-driver-390. nvidia-driver-390 is the NVIDIA driver metapackage. All lower version nvidia-driver packages in Ubuntu 22.04 are transitional packages for installing nvidia-driver-390.
To install nvidia-driver-390 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 
sudo reboot  

